# Angular application and Drupal services

Tags: 7, services

I am creating an Angular application using headless Drupal. I am using Drupal services module for web services.

I am trying to implement login mechanism in this app. Login is working fine but to handle authenticated requests, it is necessary to use "Cookie" header in each service call.

My app doesn't allow to use cookie header. In my browser console it says as

"Cookie unsafe header is not allowed". Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: I am not having this issue with an angular.js front end that connects to a headless Drupal 7 site using the services module. I make a request to the "login" action. This returns a response with a Response Cookie set. Subsequent http requests made using `$http` in my angular service works fine. I also use 'system/connect' action with a CSRF token and I get a proper response.

Comment: Can you please tell me the headers name and value  you used to set for subsequent authenticated calls?

Comment: I am not adding any particular headers other than `X-CSRF-Token`. I use `$http.get({url: '/path/to/user/login', data: {username: '', password: ''}, method: 'POST', headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': 'token'}});` and `$http.get({url: '/path/to/user/' + id, method: 'PUT', headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': 'new token'}, data: userData});`

Comment: Thanks. For new token, you are replacing with token value  obtained from login response. Right?

Comment: It's probably a CORS problem; check your server/app settings for allowed cross origin headers

Comment: No, the CSRF token comes from the services token end point.

Comment: @Clive I am allowing Cookie header at my server side. Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Cookie ,X-CSRF-Token'. Still getting same error "Refused to set unsafe header Cookie"

Answer (score 0):

I have similar setup where i use drupal as back-end and connect to services with Angular app (Ionic App) and i am describing the sequence below; however, you need to consider the below reference if you are doing cross domain

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007572/angular2-xhrfields-withcredentials-true/

And you have to setup CORS (This is my config for reference)

API/*||POST,GET|Content-Type,x-csrf-token,Authorization|true

1. Login to your drupal service

   End Point: /user/login

   Payload:{"username":"username","password":"userpass"}

   Content-Type: application/json

   Method:Post

   Result: User information & Token

**Request**

[image]

2. Get the Token and use it in subsequent requests by setting the header to X-CSRF-Token

   End Point: /node/100

   Payload:Empty

   Content-Type: application/json

   Method:Get

   Result: Node information

**Request With X-CSRF-Token header**

[image]

3. Logout from drupal service (Token must be set as well)

   End Point: /user/logout

   Payload:Empty

   Content-Type: application/json

   Method:Post

   Result: [true]